# How to enable LSP for Javascript in Sublime text 3

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

How to enable javascript intellisense in *Sublime text 3* using **[LSP](https://lsp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**.

I did the following, but still the features not working :-

- Install sublime text 3 for windows 8.1
- Install Nodejs latest version with NPM
- Add `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm` to User PATH
- Install *package control* and then **LSP** package
- Install `npm install -g javascript-typescript-langserver` wrapper server
- select `LSP: Enable Language Server` from the command palette
- open *javascript* file ended with *.js*

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The documentation mentions that you need to select `LSP: Enable Language Server` from the command palette to enable the server; did you do that?

Comment: yes I did it globally and in project but still not working