# Sublime Text 4 - How To Setup LSP-eslint

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb, language-server-protocol, sublimetext4

When using Sublime text 3 I had ***SublimeLinter*** with ***SublimeLinter-eslint*** packages, along with ***eslint*** & ***babel-eslint*** global node modules for JS & JSX syntax.

With the switch to Sublime 4 I decided to give [LSP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) a try. I Installed it, also [LSP-css](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-css) (which ran fine out of the box) & [LSP-eslint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-eslint), which couldn't get to work.

If I check Sublime's status bar I see the language server apparently running (?)
[image]

This is within a project with it's own `eslintrc.js` config file, which works out of the box in VScode. Part of it below:

```
const RulesAirBnb = require("eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/best-practices");
const RulesCRA = require("eslint-config-react-app");

module.exports = {
    root: true,

    parser: "babel-eslint",
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: "module",
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
            generators: true,
        },
    },

    extends: [
        "airbnb", // Baseguide is AirBnB"s
        "prettier",
        "prettier/react",
    ],
```

- How to make it work?
- Do I still need global node modules of ***eslint*** & ***babel-eslint***? (considering I have both locally under dev dependencies in the package.json of the project - sounds to me I shouldn't)

Checked the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60064124/how-to-enable-lsp-for-javascript-in-sublime-text-3) but no luck.

Comment: If it's shown in the status bar, then it is running. Did you try configuring it following the [directions in the README](https://github.com/sublimelsp/LSP-eslint#readme)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt, long live dads! I actually went through it (readme) and from what I gathered it should be working out of the box upon installation as lsp-css did (?). Also, I wonder the same, seems like it's running fine in status bar, but if I make some mistakes on the JSX file nothing shows up, whether SublimeLinter would highlight them. I spent a few hours researching the web but unfortunately there is not much info about lsp-eslint or even a setup walkthrough within Sublime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing [LSP-typescript](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-typescript) did the trick, works out of the box, lsp-eslint not even needed. Unreal.

Found the info [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-get-visual-studio-code-like-intellisense-in-sublime-text/42956/14) after days of research (thanks chrsap!).

If you are running ST3, check [LSP-typescript's readme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-typescript) for needed packages.

Comment: Well typescript does different things than eslint. It's not a 1:1 replacement.